# How and where to call my Task when extending AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am having difficulties understanding AsyncTask, even after reading everything about it on Developer.Android. I am looking for some insight in how I should proceed. This is the situation :

I have an Activity which, on an onClick event calls the LoginCheck() method of an underlying LoginController class. The LoginController class then proceeds to fetch whatever information is nescesarry from a UserInfo class or from the Activity(User and Password) and creates an instance of a RestClient which then makes the call to the web service and attempts to log in. RestClient has a private class CallServiceTask that extends AsyncTask.

I have a few design problems here that I hope you can be of assistance with.

- Am I doing it right? Is  this a proper way to make sure that any calls to the web service are being done asynchronously?
- How do use onProgressUpdate or whatever to notify the user that the application is in the process of logging in?
- How would I go about getting the data that is saved in DoinBackground() ?

Below you'll find snippets of the project in question :

*RestClient*

```
// From the constructor...
rtnData = new Object[]{ new JSONObject() , Boolean.TRUE  };

   public void ExecuteCall(RequestMethod method) throws Exception
{
    Object[] parameters = new Object[]{ new HttpGet() , new String("") };
    switch(method) {
        case GET:
        {
            //add parameters
            String combinedParams = "";
            if(!params.isEmpty()){
                combinedParams += "?";
                for(NameValuePair p : params)
                {
                    String paramString = p.getName() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue());
                    if(combinedParams.length() > 1)
                    {
                        combinedParams  +=  "&" + paramString;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        combinedParams += paramString;
                    }
                }
            }

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url + combinedParams);

            //add headers
            for(NameValuePair h : headers)
            {
                request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
            }
            parameters[0] = request;
            parameters[1] = url;

            new CallServiceTask().execute(request, url);


            jsonData = ((JSONObject) rtnData[0]).optJSONObject("data");
            connError = (Boolean) rtnData[1];
            break;

        }
        case POST: ....

    }
}

private Object[] executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, String url)
{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client = getNewHttpClient();

    HttpResponse httpResponse;

    try {
        httpResponse = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {

            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            String response = convertStreamToString(instream);
            try {
                rtnData[0] = new JSONObject(response);
                rtnData[1] = false;

            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                rtnData[1] = true;
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
            instream.close();
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e)  {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rtnData;
}
```

*CallServiceTask*

```
    private class CallServiceTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object[]>
{

    protected Object[] doInBackground(Object... params) 
    {
        HttpUriRequest req = (HttpUriRequest) params[0];
        String url = (String) params[1];

        return executeRequest(req, url);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object[] result) 
    {
             rtnData = result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely right that any possibly long running operations should be executed in separate threads. And the `AsyncTask` is a good way to solve this kind of problems, since it also gives you an easy way to synchronize your task with the UI thread. This is the answer to your first question.

Now, concerning the UI thread updating to show your users that your application is not stuck. Since an `AsyncTask`'s `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` methods are running inside the UI thread, you can easily create, run and stop `ProgressDialog`s or `ProgressBar`s there. If you want to show the current progress of the task, you should call `publishProgress(int)` method inside the `doInBackground()`, and then make use of it inside the `AsyncTask`'s `onProgressUpdate()` method. There you can, for example, update your `ProgressDialog`.

And to get the result out of your AsyncTask you can either call its `get()` method (this a synchronous call), or implement some kind of callback interface that will tell the activity that the task has finished.

I hope the answer is clear enough, if no - feel free to ask more questions. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Create an interface called, for example, `onFetchFinishedListener` with one method - `void onFetchFinished(String)`. Your activity, that starts the `AsyncTask`, must implement this interface. Now create a constructor inside your `AsyncTask` that takes an `OnFetchFinishedListener` object as an argument, and when instantiating the `AsyncTask` inside your activity send a reference to the `Activity` as the argument (since it implements `OnFetchFinishedListener`). Then when your task is finished inside `doInBackground()` call `onFetchFinished()` on the activity. Now inside the `onFetchFinished(String)` method of your `Activity` you can make use of the `String` (or another object) that's brought with the callback. Again, hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Your answer was pretty helpful but still leaves a couple of questions in my mind. I keep reading things like "Runs on the UI thread"  and runs inside the UI thread. does this mean that I can simply call stuff like ProgressDialog from within OnPreExecute in my CallServiceTask class and the UI elements will automatically appear on the screen?

Now As for the callback interface that all sounds pretty greek to me. I will have to read further about it :)

Comment: @litemode, 1) Yes, you can create things like Dialogs right inside the onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() methods, 2) I'll try to edit my answer to explain a bit callback interfaces.